# Rendering a template getting the data from a model in Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm having some issues with rendering my view in backbone getting the data from my model so I'd appreciate any help. Here goes my html code:

```
<ul id="datos">

</ul>

<script type="text/template" id="listado-template"> 
    <h2>Mi listado</h2>
    <li>Item 1: <%= item1 %></li>
</script>

<script>
    modelo = new Modelo();    
    modeloView = new ModeloView({model: modelo});
</script>
```

And this are my model and my view:

```
Modelo = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: 'myurljson',
});

Backbone.View.extend({ 
    tagName: "ul",

    el: "#datos",

    template: _.template($('#listado-template').html()),

    initialize: function() {    
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this); 
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.append(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});
```

The problem is my template is not renderized well. I'm getting an undefined error with `item1`. But if I delete this tag `li`, the tag `h2` is renderized so I guess the problem is in getting my data from my model through "myurljson". Any help? Thank you!

Comment: did you `fetch` your model?

Comment: Yes. I do `modelo.fetch` when I want to render this Backbone.View

Answer (score 2):

Underscore will fail if you try to render an undefined variable. See this Fiddle trying to reproduce your problem : http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/PELfV/

You can

- define a default `item1` property in your model wit a sensible value

  ```
  Modelo = Backbone.Model.extend({
      urlRoot: 'myurljson',
      defaults: {
          item1: ''
      }
  });
  ```

  A demo at http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/PELfV/1/
- or test the value before printing it

  ```
  <script type="text/template" id="listado-template"> 
      <li>Item 1: <% if (typeof item1!=="undefined") print(item1) %></li>
  </script>
  ```

  And its demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/PELfV/2/

Comment: You've partially solved the problem. Now I dont get that error but there is no render data. And I can assure 'myurljson' return the data I'm trying to render.

Comment: The template I get is `Item 1: ` when I run my code. I mean I'm getting the property value from `myurljson' but althought It has a value, it is not render it.

Comment: Could you show the raw JSON returned by your server? Here's what should happen, with a default value and a set occurring later http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/PELfV/3/

Comment: `[{"id":1,"item1":10, ...}]` I dont know where the problem can be.

Comment: You're replying with an array (a collection for Backbone) but your code expects an object : try sending `{"id":1,"item1":10, ...}` without the enclosing [ ] . If you can't, you will have to decide if you want to handle a collection client side.

Comment: I'll give it a try using a collection. Thanks!